# Ellipsoids and lattices: an enclosure problem.

Tags: lattices, geometry

*$E \subset {\mathbb R}^2$ is an ellipse of area $1$ centered at the origin that contains no other point with integer coordinates. Is there a matrix $A \in SL(2,{\mathbb Z})$ such that the ellipse $A(E)$ is contained in a disc of radius 10?*

Hopefully, this is really easy and it is only my ignorance in "reduction theory" (or other similar techniques) that is at the heart of my difficulties.

More generally, given an ellipsoid $E$ of unit volume in ${\mathbb R}^n$ centered at the origin and containing no other point with integer coordinates, I'm interested in a good upper estimate of the size of the ball in which I can enclose $A(E)$ for some matrix $A \in SL(n,{\mathbb Z})$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, such $A$ exists, and the radius can be much smaller than $10$; indeed radius $2^{1/2}$ suffices regardless of the area of $E$.

Write the ellipse $A(E)$ as $ax^2+bxy+cy^2 \leq 1$.  By reduction theory of binary quadratic forms, we can choose the ${\rm SL}_2({\bf Z})$ transformation $A$ to obtain coefficients satisfying $|b| \leq a \leq c$.  But $a \geq 1$ because $(x,y)=(1,0)$ is not in the interior of the ellipse.  Hence
$$
Q(x,y) \geq a(x^2 - |xy| + y^2) \geq x^2 - |xy| + y^2 \geq \frac12(x^2+y^2)
$$
for all $x,y \in \bf R$.  Therefore $A(E)$ is contained in the disc $\frac12(x^2+y^2) \leq 1$ of radius $2^{1/2}$, **QED**.

Equality holds only for $a=|b|=c=1$, in which case the ellipse has area $2\pi/\sqrt{3}$; for an ellipse of area $1$ one can improve the bound slightly using the condition $4ac-b^2=4\pi$, but the best $r$ is still somewhat larger than $1$.

There exist similar bounds in higher dimension $n$, but naturally it gets harder to compute or estimate them as $n$ grows, especially once $n>8$ and the shape of the cone of (say) Minkowski-reduced forms isn't known.  (NB Minkowski reduction must give *some* bound for each $n$, but probably not the best bound once we go far enough beyond $n=2$.)

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: Thanks Noam !! What would be some good references for this (reduction theory of binary, n-ary, quadratic forms)?

Comment: You're welcome.  References?  There's a huge literature, of which I know only $o(\epsilon$).  SPLAG lists several references on page 397, and gives explicit criteria for Minkowski reduction for the first few $n$.  Anyhow the case $n=2$ is entirely classical: the first reduced basis vector is the shortest nonzero lattice vector, and the second is the shortest that's not a multiple of the first.  [SPLAG = *Sphere Packings, Lattices, and Groups* by Conway and Sloane; the acronymic nickname is not disrespectful because it is used by the authors themselves.] 

Answer (score 2):

This is an addition to Noam's answer. In higher dimensions the same type of reasoning---using explicit conditions on the coefficients of reduced quadratic forms---is not feasible. Nevertheless, it is possible to prove the following result:

**Theorem.** Let $E \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be an $n$-dimensional ellipsoid centered at the origin and containing no other integer point. There exists a transformation $T \in GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ such that $T(E)$ is contained in the ball of radius
$$
\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{(n-1)(n-2)/2} \frac{2^n}{\epsilon_n}\sqrt{n^{n-1}}
$$
centered at the origin.

Here $\epsilon_n$ is the volume of the unit ball of dimension $n$.

This theorem follows easily from the following two results:

**Theorem.** Given a positive-definite $n \times n$ matrix  $A = (a_{ij})$, there exists a unimodular integer matrix $U$ such that the matrix $A' = (a'_{ij})$
defined by $A' := U^t A U$ satisfies the following inequality:
$$
\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{(n-1)(n-2)} \left(\frac{\epsilon_n}{2^n}\right)^2 \leq \frac{\det(A')}{a'_{11} a'_{22} \cdots a'_{nn}}  .
$$

**Theorem.** If $A = (a_{ij})$ is a positive-definite $n \times n$ matrix, then for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have that
$$
\frac{\det(A)}{n^{n-1}a_{11} a_{22} \cdots a_{nn}} \sum a_{ii} x_i^2 \leq \sum a_{ij} x_i x_j \leq n \sum a_{ii} x_i^2 .
$$

The first of these two results is an important theorem of Minkowski on the reduction of positive quadratic forms (see Theorem 3 in page 69 of Lekkerkerker), while the second is an improved version of Lemma 4 in page 43 of Siegel's [Lectures on
Quadratic Forms](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr07.pdf).