# A spectral inequality for positive-definite matrices 

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, inequalities

**Question.** Given a positive-definite $n \times n$ matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ with eigenvalues 
$$
\lambda_1 \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n ,
$$
is there a sharp upper bound for the product $\lambda_2 \cdots \lambda_n$ in terms of the quantity
$$
\|A\|_\infty := \max_{1 \leq i, j \leq n} |a_{ij}| ?
$$

A classic inequality due to A. Hirsch states that the modulus of an eigenvalue of an $n \times n$ complex matrix $A$ is less than $n  \|A\|_\infty$, which implies that 
$$
|\lambda_2 \cdots \lambda_n| \leq n^{n-1}\|A\|_\infty^{n-1} .
$$
However, this seems like a rather rough estimate for positive-definite matrices. I'm interested in any estimate that is substantially better than this.

**Motivation.** Using Hirsch's inequality one can improve Lemma 4 in page 43 of Siegel's [Lectures on Quadratic Forms](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr07.pdf) to yield the following result:

**Theorem.**
If $A = (a_{ij})$ is a positive-definite $n \times n$ matrix, then for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have that
$$
\frac{\det(A)}{n^{n-1}a_{11} a_{22} \cdots a_{nn}} \sum a_{ii} x_i^2 \leq \sum a_{ij} x_i x_j \leq n \sum a_{ii} x_i^2 .
$$

The inequality on the left would be greatly improved if we had the sharp upper bound required in the question. This in turn would yield a better answer to this [enclosure problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87929/ellipsoids-and-lattices-an-enclosure-problem) (see my answer to that question).

**Addendum.** If we apply the estimate in Suvrit's answer in the proof of the theorem above, the inequality is indeed improved to:

$$
\frac{\det(A)}{2^{n-1}a_{11} a_{22} \cdots a_{nn}} \sum a_{ii} x_i^2 \leq \sum a_{ij} x_i x_j \leq n \sum a_{ii} x_i^2 .
$$

In fact, in the proof the estimate  for $\lambda_2 \cdots \lambda_n$ is applied to an auxiliary matrix $B = (b_{ij})$ whose diagonal entries are all $1$ and for which $|b_{ij}| < 1$ if $i \neq j$.

In turn this yields the following improved bound for the [enclosure problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87929/ellipsoids-and-lattices-an-enclosure-problem):

**Theorem.** Let $E \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be an $n$-dimensional ellipsoid centered at the origin and containing no other integer point. There exists a transformation $T \in GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ such that $T(E)$ is contained in the ball of radius
$$
\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{(n-1)(n-2)/2} \frac{2^n}{\epsilon_n}\sqrt{2^{n-1}}
$$
centered at the origin.

Here $\epsilon_n$ is the volume of the unit ball of dimension $n$.

*Does anyone know a better bound?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\newcommand{\trace}{\operatorname{trace}}$ 
The result below mentions a reasonably improved inequality.

Let $m = \frac{\trace(A)}{n}$, and $s^2= \frac{\trace(A^2)}{n}-m^2$. Then, [Wolkowicz and Styan](http://orion.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/henry/reports/bndseigs80.pdf) (*Linear Algebra and its Applications*, 29:471-508, 1980), show that

\begin{equation*}
 \lambda_1 \ge \frac{\det(A)}{(m+s/\sqrt{n-1})^{n-1}}
\end{equation*}

*Remark:* As per the notation in the OP, $\lambda_1$ is the smallest eigenvalue---usually the literature uses $\lambda_1$ to be largest.

Thus, we obtain the upper bound
\begin{equation*}
 \lambda_2\lambda_3\cdots\lambda_n \le \left(m+ \frac{s}{\sqrt{n-1}}\right)^{n-1}.
\end{equation*}
This bound is tight. Consider for example,
If $A= \text{Diag}(1,2,2,\ldots,2)$, then the lhs is $2^{n-1}$, $m=2-1/n$, and $s^2 
= 1/n-1/n^2$, so that $s/\sqrt{n-1} = 1/n$. Thus, the bound on the rhs is tight.

With $M := \max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$, we see that $m \le M$ and $s^2 \le nM^2 - m^2$, which leads to an upper bound in terms of $M$ as desired

\begin{equation*}
 \lambda_2\lambda_3\cdots\lambda_n \le \left(M+ \sqrt{\frac{nM^2-m^2}{n-1}}\right)^{n-1} < \left(M + M\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}} \right)^{n-1},
\end{equation*}
which is better than the bound mentioned in the post (though we lost a bit by deleting $m^2$).

Comment: Thanks Suvrit ! Your answer plus the argument to prove the theorem in the OP yields a very neat result (see the edited question).



Comment: By the way, it is $s^2 \leq n M^2 - m^2$, right? It makes no difference to the applications I had in mind, because I'm interested in the case $m = M = 1$.

Comment: Oops, sorry, you are right, it should be $nM^2-m^2$! When typing it up, I felt the $\sqrt{M}$ factor to be a bit odd. Let me update the answer! Thanks.