# Determinant and eigenvalues of a specific matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

This came up in a conversation with an engineer friend of mine.

Let $c>0$ be a constant. Let $A_{ij}$ be an $n$ by $n$ matrix with entries
$$
A_{ij} = e^{-c(i-j)^2}.
$$
Is there a name for this matrix? What is known, perhaps approximately or asymptotically as 
$c$ and $n$ change about the determinant and the eigenvalues of it? Are there other functions
of $(i-j)$ for which the answer is more explicit?

Comment: If you let $e^{-c}$ be $x$, then the matrix has polynomial entries in $x$, and experiment seems to indicate that the determinant is a product of cyclotomic polynomials (for instance, if $n = 6$, we get $-(x-1)^{15}(x+1)^{15}(x^2+1)^6 (x^2-x+1)^3(x^2+x+1)^3(x^4+1)^2(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$. (In particular, the power of $(x \pm 1)$ seems to be $n$ choose $2$.)

Comment: It's an example of a Toeplitz matrix.  The entries are Gaussian.  So I googled Gaussian Toeplitz matrix which gave the following paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379592902559 , which should answer your question.  (I haven't read the paper myself so can't say for sure.)

Comment: This is also a totally positive matrix, in the sense of Gantmakher-Krein. Which implies that all eigenvalues are real and many qualitative properties of eigenfunctions

Comment: This is also an aproximation to the heat kernel in some sense

Comment: Formula (3.1) says the determinant is
$$
(1-a^2)^{n-1}
(1-a^4)^{n-2}
\cdots
(1-a^{2(n-2)})^2
(1-a^{2(n-1)})
= \prod_{m=1}^{n-1} (1-a^{2m})^{n-m}
$$
where $a = e^{-c}$ is what Abhinav called $x$.  The $n=6$ case agrees
with Abhinav's factorization, and yes, the valuations at $1-a$ and $1+a$
are both $n \choose 2$.  (In the paper the size of the matrix is called
$k$, not $n$.)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the comments, I will take a look!

Answer (score 6):

To answer the question: "...is there a name for this matrix..."

Beyond the "Gaussian-Toeplitz matrix" mentioned in the comments, the said matrix is a special case of the *Gaussian Kernel* (which is also the alluded to "heat kernel"):

\begin{equation*}
 k(x_i,x_j) = e^{-c(x_i-x_j)^2}\qquad x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation*}
Clearly, the matrix $A = [k(x_i,x_j)]$ is semidefinite. If the $x_i$s are unique, then it is strictly positive definite (this requires some more work to prove).

The Gaussian kernel is of course the canonical example of a *translation invariant kernel*, so searching more for such kernel matrices should bring up more examples, namely, matrices of the form $A_{ij} = k(x_i,x_j)=\varphi(x_i-x_j)$, for suitable $\varphi$.

Incidentally, in the paper mentioned by @Lucia, the smallest eigenvalue for the Gaussian-Toeplitz $A$ is bounded from below by (assuming $A$ is $n\times n$):
\begin{equation*}
  \lambda_n \ge \frac{\det(A)}{n!}.
\end{equation*}
It seems possible to improve this to $\lambda_n \ge \frac{\det(A)}{2^{n-1}}$ by using the technique mentioned [in my answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/128953/8430).

Answer (score 5):

Just a followup to @Lucia's comment, [here is the paper:](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5188175/toeplitz.pdf)